# Rearrange list of tuples by another sorted enumerated list

Tags: python, list

I have one list of tuples:
`a = [(10, 11), (5, 5), (2, 3), (6, 7), (8, 3), (9, 2)]` and one simple list with values `b = [10, 9, 10, 2, 8, 3]`. Then I enumerate the second list and sort it for some purposes.

```
b_enumerated = list(enumerate(b))
# [(0, 10), (1, 9), (2, 10), (3, 2), (4, 8), (5, 3)]
b_sorted = sorted(b_enumerated, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
# [(0, 10), (2, 10), (1, 9), (4, 8), (5, 3), (3, 2)]
```

Now I want to rearrange my first list according to the second sorted list, so I expect to get `[(10, 11), (2, 3), (5, 5), (8, 3), (9, 2), (6, 7)]` (tuples of the original list in index order of the ordered list: 0, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3), where, for example, my enumerated first list is `[(0, (10, 11)), (1, (5, 5)), (2, (2, 3)), (3, (6, 7)), (4, (8, 3)), (5, (9, 2))]`.

How can I achieve the expected result? Maybe I need to use some sort of indexing, because sorting zipped lists didn't help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the purpose is to sort `a` with the reversed order of `b`, you don't need to enumerate `b` and sort the enumerated sequence to build an intermediary list of `b_sorted` in the first place.

Instead, you can zip `b` with `a` for sorting and then output only the second item in the resulting sequence of tuples:

```
[t for _, t in sorted(zip(b, a), reverse=True)]
```

This returns:

```
[(10, 11), (2, 3), (5, 5), (8, 3), (9, 2), (6, 7)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Answer**

```
a_sorted =  [a[i[0]] for i in b_sorted]
```

**Brief Explanation**

You're basically trying to say 'send `a[0]` to `a_sorted[0]`, send `a[1]` to `a_sorted[2]` ... send `a[i]` to `a_sorted[b_sorted[i][0]]`'.

This can be done with the code

```
a_sorted =  [a[b_sorted[i][0]] for i in range(len(b_sorted))]
```

which works fine but can be shortened and arguably neatened by instead iterating over `b_sorted`.

```
a_sorted =  [a[i[0]] for i in b_sorted]
```